# Early game food problems

Tags: banished

Not so sure how well fishers work. I have had food problems since I started. I had half of my population fishing, people were dying left and right, and then I moved that up to 100% and they are all still just barely not starving to death.

But I has just run of of firewood, and almost out of tools, and have almost no stone, and I still need to build a blacksmith. But I do not have a single free laborer to do anything. Are fishers only supposed to produce enough food for themselves and maybe their kids?

I used to think it was that I only had a wagon and it was farish away. But I built a storage barn finally quite a bit ago, and people were still dying left and right.

What I do not get about gathers (which everyone recommends) is how they are supposed to be efficient. They cannot be next to houses/storage, so every basket of food they get requires a 2 day trek to get it into town. How is that supposed to work out?

Conversely, my fishermen produce boxes of fish pretty constantly, and even right next to a storage shed a significant amount of their time is going back and forth.

What am I doing wrong, how are gatherers supposed to work with such a long required travelling time? Do I just place them on the edge of forests, butting up against my town? SO onyl half the circle is used, but they are right next to a storage shed and houses?

Comment: It is possible my main problem is lack of tools, but still the Fishermen appear to be making loads of food, it is just always constantly eaten.

Comment: Are your fishing huts on a lake, or on a river?

Comment: On a River. not overlapping.

Comment: You should also take into consideration whether you have a Market distributing goods or not. Without a market food tends to get dispersed very unevenly and some people can end up starving. The Market helps keep everyone fed reasonably. You could in fact have quite enough food for your town, but if the goods aren't being distributed evenly it wont matter

Comment: I only have like 6 citizens, they are all like 5 tile walk from the storage barn.


but I have heard it implied that markets somehow make food sharing between households better as well? You get less of one house hoarding an entire years worth of food, and others starving.

Comment: @JonathonWisnoski That's exactly what the markets are for. =D

Comment: A weird update about Fisheries. I started another game and had a similar problem (but was no longer relying on fisheries). For year after you, even in very efficient situations, I was producing basically just enough to feed the workers themselves. Maybe 500 for 4 workers a season, or a little less. It is a place you can easily throw extra workers in to basically earn their keep but nothing else.
But suddenly last year Production doubled. Everything was the exact same as all previous years, just production went up in both.

Comment: I have heard similarly weird thing about hunters, basically just making enough to feed themselves.
But I have always found them very very effective (like 1000 meat for 3 workers).

Maybe both of these buildings rely on some hidden populations? Maybe my lake just started with low levels of fish and they had to replenish?

Comment: Gatherer huts OP.  Place them relatively far away from your settlement. The food grows better in dense untouched bush.

Comment: You should include a picture of your town, since I expect it's still very small and we can see most of it.

Answer (score 4):

Fisherman are a great supplement for your food stores, but I wouldn't rely on them exclusively. I don't know how your setup looks, but you also have to make sure that their areas don't overlap at all. It will destroy your efficiency.

When you first start out, the best options for food are Gatherer Huts. Place them in the middle of a forest so the entire circle is completely filled with trees to maximize their output. Make sure that you get a Forester log next to them to plant more trees for them to gather from as well. This should hold you over for a pretty good amount of time before you need to start expanding into things like Fields, Orchards, etc.

Edit::Completely missed the second part of your question. Sorry

As for how Gatherers are supposed to be efficient, look into what is referred to as the "Forest(er) Cluster".

These are when you place a Forester(set to plant), Herbalist, Gatherer and Hunter all right against each other. The Forester will provide the trees necessary to reach maxium output of the other buildings. Make sure that you set this up in an area with as few hills, mountains, streams, rivers or anything else trees will not grow on as possible, agian to achieve maximum output from the Forester.

Once you have this set up you have a few options. I've seen many people place a couple houses directly in the forest cluster, but personally I like to set up a little living/storage area just outside of the tree line so I don't take up anymore growth space. This will provide the workers for each of these buildings a place to live, eat, stay warm and drop off goods so they don't have to walk too far anymore.

Answer (score 4):

All of the production buildings in game benefit from short travel distances, but they do so differently. Fishing huts should include as much water in their radius as possible, their production is heavily dependent on that, so put them on a spot where they have less land in their radius (where rivers meet lakes etc). Put a storage barn overlapping its "road" with the one of the fishing hut, than place 2 houses right next to them. Same for crops/orchads, they get the same benefit from having this kind of setup. Gatherer huts, herbalists, and hunting lodges are not as dependent on closeness to storage and houses. Keep those just outside the radius of this food buildings, if you use a forester, keep its workers numbers low (one or two) and set it on plant mode only. Because this food buildings have huge working areas and food can "spawn" anywhere in that radius its best not to waste "tree space" by having houses and storage barns inside working areas. Hope it helps :),

Answer (score 3):

I've found that fishermen work just fine for the first few years, and I rarely setup a gathering hut until year 2 or 3.

My strategy is to build 1-2 Fishing docks and 2 crop fields. I assign 2 farmers to the crop fields, and 2 fishermen. After the farmers finish gathering the crops for the winter, I re-assign them to be fishermen, and sometimes I'll even setup 6 total fishermen during the winter.

If you do this, remember to re-assign the 2 farmers when spring comes!

Comment: Farms a tricky to start out with because of how the food is produced. Instead of the steady stream of stock that a Gatherer Hut or Fishing Dock provide, you're essentially living off of what you already have until Fall when the crops are harvested, making the time up to the first harvest especially difficult. Due to this, farms aren't typically recommended in the first couple years. Build a stable supply with something else and then start adding farms.

Comment: I don't find a problem with it. Sure it's not a steady stream of food, but I never find an issue having enough food during summer and fall as long as I have 2-3 fishermen. I usually get more food by the beginning of winter this way than I do fishing, so it's a nominal boost.

Comment: Farms are weird like that for me. Sometimes they're fine, other times they let me down in the early game. I've just started going with the thought process that there are more reliable sources early on. Personally I don't find them worth the risk too early.

Comment: I don't see any difference as long as I keep to the same structure. That is making sure my farms are sizable (100-125 squares each typically) and that I start them right away.

Comment: Maybe I expand too fast then because I've starved out a number of towns by building farms right off the bat.

Comment: I am sort of confused about farming.
What determines what you are allowed to designate to plant? I built an orchard, and only cherry was available, also the choices for the farm were similarly random seeming. As far as I know I do not have any seeds of any kind, does the ability to select it mean that I have sherries hidden away somewhere?

Comment: You begin with 2 random types of crop and 1 type of random tree. Everything after that you need to buy from traders.